# Rails link_to for truncated html using helpers end up with undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to truncate posts that are over 250 to include a link to the show page. In my controller I have:

Right now I have in my index view:

```
<% @posts.includes(:categories, :author).each do |posts| %>
<%= truncate_html posts.content.html_safe, :length => 250, omission:'...Continue Reading' %>
<%= link_to "...Continue Reading", post_path(posts.url_name)%>
```

It loads properly with no errors. Right now the omission section doesn't click over to a new page so I added in the link_to. I then tried something like:

```
<%= truncate_html posts.content.html_safe, :length => 250, link_to: "...Continue Reading", post_path(posts.url_name) %>
```

Ended up with the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ", post_path(posts.url_name) );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ^
```

So I decided to try and build it out in a helper and just plug the helper in instead. For my helper I built out:

```
def post_length
 output = truncate(@posts.content, length: 250)
 output += link_to('...Continue Reading', post_path(posts.url_name)) if post.content.size > 250
 output.html_safe
end
```

Then put in my index the following:

```
<%= post_length %>
```

I end up getting undefined method 'content'. I've tried doing in the helper: posts.content, post.content, @post.content, etc. Does not work. Am I doing the helper wrong?

I've also tried the following:

```
def post_truncate(&block)
truncate(@posts.content,
  length: 250,
  separator: ' ',
  omission: "...") {
    link_to "Something", post_path(posts.url_name)
  }
  )
end
```

I end up with syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

Comment: Looking at the example code, `posts` isn't an instance variable. I can't see where its getting set. It also feels like its a `post`(singular) rather than `posts`(plural).

The reason why posts is undefined in the helper is exactly that. `@posts` would be available, but its not an instance variable. `post` doesn't exist in that context. As a fix that should work(regardless of the naming conventions), pass `posts` into `post_length`. Then use whatever you called the method param instead of `@posts` and `post`.

Not really an answer as im not sure if its correct or not.

Comment: in the last example you get that error (`unexpected ')'`) because you really do have an unexpected `)` one line before the `end` ....  ill make an answer with the proper code

Answer (score 0):

Quasi-answer that worked:

```
<%= raw (truncate_html posts.content.html_safe, :length =>500, :omission => "...#{link_to 'Continue Reading', post_path(posts.url_name)}") %>
```

Did not end up using a helper but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote in the comment:

In the last example you get that error :

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

because you really do have an unexpected `)` one line before the end.
The closing `)` is right after the `ommision: "..."` so you dont need another one.

Your helper method should look like:

```
def post_truncate(&block)
  truncate(@posts.content,
    length: 250,
    separator: ' ',
    omission: "...") {
      link_to "Something", post_path(posts.url_name)
    }
end
```

I my opinion this is the correct way of using the `link_to` to add the link, and not using string interpolation like you did in your answer